# desktop приложение на Electron и Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, electron

мой вопрос заключается в следующем: в проекте присутствует локальный сервер на Mongodb и desktop приложение написанное на Electron, как связать приложение с моей бд, чтобы приложение запрашивало и получало данные с вышеупомянутого сервера. Благодарю за внимание. уточню: по отдельности скрипты работают, как подключить мой server.js(в котором находится mongo клиент) к app.js в котором расположено приложение

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно подключить к приложению библиотеку [Mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose). С её помощью Вы сможете установить подключение к MongoDb и выполнять все необходимые операции.

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую